# TCPDF: Rotate text in HTML table

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I have a problem. Trying to rotate text in table, which I created like this:

```
$tbl = '<table border="1" style="text-align: center;">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Year, month, day</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Person</th>
  </tr>
</table>';
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_4, true, false, false, true, '');
```

I want to rotate first "th" 90 degrees, I mean set text from bottom to top, like in this photo. [image: photo]

Comment: Use this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/ for the text you want to rotate.

Comment: TCPDF doesn't fully support CSS, so this not work for me. But thank you for advice.